# forward expects 1 arguments (0 given)

Tags: python, tkinter, typeerror, turtle-graphics

```
from turtle import *
from Tkinter import *

class TurtleApp:
    def left(self):
            self.turtle.right(90)
    def forward(self):
            self.turtle.forward(self.step)
    def right(self):
            self.turtle.right(90)
    def backward(self):
            self.turtle.backward(self.step)


    def __init__(self):
            self.main = Tk()
            self.main.title('TurtleApp')
            self.step = 10
            self.turtle = Turtle()
            self.window = Screen()
            self.window.setup(500,500)
            self.turtle.speed(self.step)
            topFrame = Frame(self.main)
            topFrame.pack(side='top')
            topLabel = Label(topFrame, text='Turtle Controls')
            topLabel.pack()
            self.createDirectionPad()
            self.createStepEntry()

    def createDirectionPad(self):
            leftFrame = Frame(self.main)
            leftFrame.pack(side='left')
            leftButton = Button(leftFrame, text='Left',command=left)
            forwardButton = Button(leftFrame, text='Forward',command=forward)
            rightButton = Button(leftFrame, text='Right',command=right)
            backwardButton = Button(leftFrame, text='Backward',command=backward)
            leftButton.grid(row=1,column=0)
            forwardButton.grid(row=0,column=1)
            rightButton.grid(row=1,column=2)
            backwardButton.grid(row=2,column=1)

    def createStepEntry(self):
            rightFrame = Frame(self.main)
            rightFrame.pack(side='right')
            stepLabel = Label(rightFrame,text='Enter step size')
            stepLabel.pack(side='top')
            stepEntry = Entry(rightFrame)
            stepEntry.pack()
            stepButton = Button(rightFrame,text='Change step size')
            stepButton.pack(side='bottom')


root = TurtleApp()

root.main.mainloop()
```

When I run this and then click on the "Forward" button, I get a type error saying that 0 arguments were given. Other than self (which is already given?) I don't know what to pass to it. Is there something I am missing here, or is it just so poorly planned that it is unable to move the turtle?

Comment: Could you please include Turtle class as well?

Comment: Include Turtle class where?

Comment: It should be `self.backward`, `self.forward`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to the `forward()` method defined in your `TurtleApp` class, not to the `turtle.forward()` function defined in the `turtle` module. The latter is being called because `from turtle import *` places `forward()` into the global scope and consequently the wrong `forward()` is being called.

Change the code in `createDirectionPad()` to use `self` when referring to your class's methods:

```
    leftButton = Button(leftFrame, text='Left',command=self.left)
    forwardButton = Button(leftFrame, text='Forward',command=self.forward)
    rightButton = Button(leftFrame, text='Right',command=self.right)
    backwardButton = Button(leftFrame, text='Backward',command=self.backward)
```